# Swift: How to read specific user data based on user id in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've been researching for days now and I wasn't able to find a solution. I'm using the firebase database as a back-end for my app. How can I use the unique user id as a way to read specific user data? I have a list of users and each user has their own data, the issue now is that when I select one of the users I see the data of all the users, instead of just the user I selected. I want to be able to view each user data by selecting it from the tableview. Any help?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class detailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //connecting table view
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCards: UITableView!

    // defining firebase reference var
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    // list to store card details
    var cardList = [CardModel]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cardList.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // creating a cell using the custom class
        let cell = tableViewCards.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        // the card object
        let card: CardModel

        //getting the name
        card = cardList[indexPath.row]
        //adding values to labels
        cell.labelName.text = card.name
        cell.labelCompanyName.text = card.company
        cell.labelRole.text = card.role
        cell.labelMobile.text = card.mobile
        cell.labelPhone.text = card.telephone
        cell.labelEmail.text = card.email
        cell.labelAddress.text = card.address

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // getting a reference to the database
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        // observing data changes
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in

            // if the reference has values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                //clearing the list
                self.cardList.removeAll()

                //iterating through all the values
                for cards in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    //getting values
                    let cardObject = cards.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let personName = cardObject?["name"]
                    let cardId = cardObject?["id"]
                    let companyName = cardObject?["company"]
                    let roleName = cardObject?["role"]
                    let mobileNo = cardObject?["mobile"]
                    let phoneNo = cardObject?["telephone"]
                    let emailAdd = cardObject?["email"]
                    let compAdd = cardObject?["address"]

                    //creating card object with model and values
                    let card = CardModel(id: cardId as! String?, name: personName as! String?, company: companyName as! String?, role: roleName as! String?, mobile: mobileNo as! String?, telephone: phoneNo as! String?, email: emailAdd as! String?, address: compAdd as! String?)

                    //appending it to the list
                    self.cardList.append(card)
                }
                //reloading to the tableView
                self.tableViewCards.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Database Structure:

```
{
  "-LOGJARYHpNDqiReJGP3" : {
    "address" : "10 test st test ",
    "company" : "grated",
    "email" : "test@email.com",
    "id" : "-LOGJARYHpNDqiReJGP3",
    "mobile" : "0412345678",
    "name" : "Jason",
    "role" : "engineer",
    "telephone" : "02999999"
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't be able to give you the exact code since, you didn't specify the structure of your Firebase database.

But you need to make a change in:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

When a user logs in you access the uid in your app via the Auth class.

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(user.uid)
```

Since you have put everything into the root node you could try:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child(user.uid)
```

You will need to look at your database, separate things out into other nodes otherwise security will be a problem for you later.

Comment: Thank You. I will check that and see how I go. I had a feeling I needed to change something in ref = Database.database().reference(), but I wasn't sure how to approach it.

Comment: I will also edit the question with my database structure

Comment: Ok so the data is in root so use the third ref.